# Pandas truncates a column width when using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to open a excel .csv file using pandas, and storing it in a variable. However, it truncates one of the strings.

[Excel .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzGia.png)

That's the file information, but when I check this is what i get.

```
                            Case Owner; Resolved Date/Time;Case Origin;Case Number;Status;Subject
Reinaldo Franco;10/16/2021      3:54 PM;Chat;20546561;Resolved;General Support                   
Catalina Sanchez;10/16/2021   5:38 AM;Chat;5625033;Resolved;Support for pay...
```

As you can see, it truncates where it says Support for pay..., and when I try to use to_csv() it doesn't save the entire column. So I think is a problem when reading the file, but not sure.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to open your file? Are you using ```pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=";")```?

Comment: I wasn't using sep=";" because even when it works, it separates each column and brings more trouble.

I just need to keep the same format so I can combine multiple files with the same format to bring a last one.

However, I was able to max the cell width by using pd.options.display.max_columns = 1000 (it is 50 by def)

Answer (score 1):

Since I needed to keep all the information in one cell and not separating it by columns, I was able to display all the information by maximizing the cell width by using: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 1000 (it is 50 by def)